# Namehash algorithm function in PHP

Tags: ens

So I am trying to create the namehash() function in PHP for my own project and to also learn how to do it.
But i am having issues.

This python function works as intended:

```
def namehash(name: str, encoding  = 'utf-8'):
if name == '':
    return b'\x00' * 32
else:
    label, _, remainder = name.partition('.')
    return sha3.keccak_256(namehash(remainder) + sha3.keccak_256(bytes(label, encoding = encoding)).digest()).digest()

namehash('') = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
namehash('eth') = 0x93cdeb708b7545dc668eb9280176169d1c33cfd8ed6f04690a0bcc88a93fc4ae
```

However this PHP function doesn not:

```
function namehash($_name){
    $node = '';

    for($i = 0; $i < 32; $i++){
        $node .= '0';
    }

    if($_name){

        $labels = explode('.', $_name);
        for($i = count($labels) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--){
            
            $labelSha = Keccak::hash($labels[$i], 256);
            $node = Keccak::hash($node . $labelSha, 256);
            
        }

    }

    return '0x' . $node;

}

0x00000000000000000000000000000000
0xc850e024ab508b89ab4833ddd18f253ddd83897cb813469cc62f68d359c5f314
```

I assume something is not encoded properly, but I am having a hard time finding what.
Can anyone show me what the issue is?

Comment: Aren't you concatenating the other way? namehash("uno.dos.tres")=keccak(namehash("dos.tres") +keccak("uno"))

Comment: @Ismael I gave up on this. both ways still generated the wrong hash.

Answer (score 1):

The [namehash](https://docs.ens.domains/dapp-developer-guide/resolving-names#reverse-resolution) for `vitalik.eth` is `0xee6c4522aab0003e8d14cd40a6af439055fd2577951148c14b6cea9a53475835`

For testing against.. you can generate namehashes (and other ENS related hashes) [here](https://ethtools.com/ens-namehash-labelhash-node-generator).
*Disclaimer: EthTools.com is my site.*

To generate a namehash in PHP using [php-keccak](https://github.com/kornrunner/php-keccak) your code would look like the following:

```
    //The base namehash for '' - 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    $baseNamehash = hex2bin("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");

    //The labelhash for 'eth' - 4f5b812789fc606be1b3b16908db13fc7a9adf7ca72641f84d75b47069d3d7f0
    $ethLabelhash = hex2bin(\kornrunner\Keccak::hash("eth", 256));

    //The namehash for 'eth' - 93cdeb708b7545dc668eb9280176169d1c33cfd8ed6f04690a0bcc88a93fc4ae
    $ethNamehash = \kornrunner\Keccak::hash($baseNamehash . $ethLabelhash, 256); 

    //The labelhash for vitalik - af2caa1c2ca1d027f1ac823b529d0a67cd144264b2789fa2ea4d63a67c7103cc
    $vitalikLabelhash = hex2bin(\kornrunner\Keccak::hash("vitalik", 256));

    //The namehash for vitalik.eth - ee6c4522aab0003e8d14cd40a6af439055fd2577951148c14b6cea9a53475835
    $vitalikNamehash = \kornrunner\Keccak::hash(hex2bin($ethNamehash) . $vitalikLabelhash, 256);
```

The important bit is using `hex2bin` to convert a hexadecimal hash string to its binary form for utilisation by the php-keccak library. Note the lack of prepending `0x`.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use the built-in PHP functions as they are less prone to errors

Here the error could be in the input value of the `$_name` parameter or in the missing implementation of the `Keccak` hash function.

You can import `sha3` library in PHP, and also add some checks to ensure there are no errors if you enter an empty input and `$node` value is **32** before returning it

Comment: What built-in function should be used?

Comment: Use `bin2hex($node)` when returning your functions it will convert binary data to a hexadecimal string

Comment: Also `str_repeat('0', 32)` to initialize the `$node` variable to 32 zeros.

Comment: And `keccak` is not really needed as `hash` is the inbuilt function